# Creating a numpy binary grid array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

My objective is to create a square binary grid in a numpy 2D array (containing only `0` and `1` values) with a given length and given number of cells per row/column. E.g.: assigning 8 cells per axis would give us a chess board (with a given length):

[image: chess_board]

Translated into code, an example would look like this (using length=8 for simplicity):

```py
res = np_binary_grid(length=8, cells_per_row=4)
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

So far I've been toying with [`np.meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html), [`np.dot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) and [`np.roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html), but all my attempts were unsuccessful (no colour on some columns, just stripes, etc...)

#### Extra

To help visualize a given matrix `M`, I am using a small routine:

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
display(Image.fromarray(M.astype(np.uint8)*255))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Try to create C-element-long vector of alternating 0/1.
- use Kronecker product to expand those elements to desired size
- Finally, use broadcasting and xoring to create an 2d chessboard

Code:

```
import numpy as np

def np_binary_grid(L, C):
    assert L % C == 0
    r = np.arange(C, dtype=np.uint8) & 1
    r = np.kron(r, np.ones(L // C, dtype=np.uint8))
    # `^ 1` fill force upper-left cell to consist of 1s
    return (r ^ 1) ^ r[:, None]

print(np_binary_grid(8, 4))
```

displays:

```
[[1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1]
 [1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1]]
```

Comment: Thanks! Right what I was looking for. I'll post my own answer too, but yours seems nicer.

Answer (score 0):

I got my own version working:

```py
def np_binary_grid(length, cells_per_row):
    '''Generates a binary grid in a numpy array.
    cells_per_row must be a power of 2'''
    aux = np.full(length, False)
    n=2
    aux[:length//n]=True
    while n<cells_per_row:
        n*=2
        aux = aux != np.roll(aux, length//n)
    
    a, b = np.meshgrid(aux, np.roll(aux, length//n))
    return (a != b).astype(np.bool)
```